# How to add an onclick event to a submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

please i am trying to add an onclick event to my button on rails 5, when click this the function is to add row to a table but its not adding row as excepted, i need help please.

```
**addRow function**

function addrow(count){
  var table = document.getElementById("result_table");
  var row = document.getElementById("result_table").lastChild;
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  for (i=0; i<count; i++)}{
    table.appendChild(clone);
  }
}
```

and the above function is in a file called **controlMenus.js** which is placed in **C:\Users\UserName\Documents\department\app\assets\javascripts** rails project directory.

```
**The view**

<div = "row">
  <div class = "col-8">
    <div class = "col-1"></div>
    <div class = "col-1 no-padding">
      <%= render 'layouts/lecturer_menu' %>
    </div>

    <div class = "col-5 no-padding  margin-left">
      <div class = "trans-background  no-padding">
        <h5 class = "pad-left centered black-font">ENTER RESULT</h5>
        <table id = "result_table"  border = "1" style="width: 100%; 
                 align: center;">
          <th>S/N</th>
          <th>MATNO</th>
          <th>NAME</th>
          <th>COURSE TITLE</th>
          <th>COURSE CODE</th>
          <th>GRADE</th>
          <th>POINT</th>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>HELLO</td>
            <td>HELLO</td>
            <td>HELLO</td>
            <td>HELLO</td>
            <td>HELLO</td>
            <td>HELLO</td>
          </tr>
          <% for i in(1..@row.to_i)do %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= i+1 %></td>
              <td>HELLO</td>
              <td>HELLO</td>
              <td>HELLO</td>
              <td>HELLO</td>
              <td>HELLO</td>
              <td>HELLO</td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>
        <%= form_for :rows, url: {controller: "lectureractivities",  
               action: "addrow"} do |f| %>
          <%= f.number_field :row, {min: 1, class: "fixed-width"} %>
          <%= submit_tag :addrows, onclick: "addrows();" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does not working mean? What have you done to debug? Have you confirmed that the js file is loading? Have you logged anything to the console to ensure that your js function variables are what you expect them to be? For starters, there are a number of errors in your html, the most glaring is in this line

```
<%= submit_tag :addrows, onclick: "addrows();" %>
```

You call a function "addrows", but your function is defined as "addrow". Try changing it to

```
<%= f.submit_tag :addrows, onclick: "addrow();" %>
```

Comment: ok thanks @margo that was a typo error **addrows()**, its now working.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please 'accept' it by clicking the checkmark or vote it up by clicking the up arrow

Comment: ya just done that @margo. thanks once more for your time.